# Changeable config values

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, configuration-files

I need to store few config values which will be changed by the application administrator. I do not want to store them in web.config files, because whenever web.config file is edited the system will recompile the application.

DBA is not letting me to create a table to store it in database.

Can you suggest some way where I can store this editable values.

Thank you for the suggestion.

it is a ASP.NET application.

Comment: @rameshdurai: this wiki ultimately ends in the web.config file, which id not desired by the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store them in your own config file. For example you could put this file inside the `~/App_Data` folder and then read the config file when you need the values. As far as the format of this file is concerned you have many choices: plain Text, XML, JSON, whatever you like.

Comment: Any sample of what? Did you already choose the format you want (XML, JSON, ...)? If you decide to use XML you could use LINQ to XML to read from the file. If you decide to use JSON you could use a JSON serializer such as the JavaScriptSerializer class that's built into the framework or a third party serializer such as JSON.NET.

Comment: If you go with XML, then you might use LINQ to XML: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could write your own `ConfigSection` and set `restartOnExternalChanges="false"`.

Then, when reading the section with `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("yourSection")` the settings will be auto-refreshed without an application restart.

If you still wish to keep web.config untouched, you can use [configSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx) property to set external file where your settings will be kept.

To design a new section you can use this tool: http://csd.codeplex.com/